# No entiendo este tipo sintaxis

Tags: python, sintaxis

Estaba revisando un código y quería saber para que sirve este tipo de sintaxis a la hora de crear una función (def). Lo que no entiendo es que tiene de diferente el echo de que la segunda función no empiece desde donde empezó la función de arriba.

```
def analizar_archivos():
    escogencia=StringVar()
    escogencia2=StringVar()
    def realizar_comparacion():
        try:
            archivo= open(entry_analisis.get()+'.txt','r')
            leer=archivo.read()
            cambio=tb(leer)
            leertrends=open(entry_analisis2.get()+'.txt','r')
            read=leertrends.read()
            cambio2=tb(read)
            def tf(word,blob):  #busca el term frequency buscando el numero de palabras en blob
                return blob.words.count(word)/len(blob.words)
```

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a que una función está identada con respecto a otra. Con el fragmento que has puesto no se puede saber para qué se hace. Te podemos dar una respuesta general, pero igual no se ajusta a lo que estás viendo.

Comment: Si lo que buscaba era una respuesta general sobre cual es el objetivo de este tipo de identación, la función trabaja en base a la otra?

Answer (score 1):

Se suele usar para:

- Crear decoradores (aunque no parece el ejemplo que has puesto)
- Protección de scopes: "proteges" la función `realizar_compaaracion()` de todo lo que sucede fuera de ella.
- Limpieza de código: en el caso de que tengas una función enorme, y quieras mantener todo claro. Aunque hay formas más fáciles y legibles para hacer esto

Answer (score 1):

Una función `f2` definida dentro de otra función `f1` es conocida sólo dentro de `f1`. Esto permite crear funciones privadas, evitando conflictos con funciones de nombre similar.

```
def f1(x):
    def f2(y):
        ...
        return some_value
    ...
    z = f2(x)
    ...
    return some_other_value
```

**Aplicación práctica**

Supón que tienes una función que retorna un json que será enviado para poblar una página web:

```
def send_status(conn):
    """Envia el estado de la aplicacion en format JSON"""

    [conn.send(line) for line in headers]

    status = dict(temperature=control.temperature,
                  humidity=control.humidity,
                  uptime=util.uptime(),
                  memfree=str(gc.mem_free()),
                  date=util.time2str(),
                  relay1="on" if machine.Pin(control.relay_gpio[0]).value() else "off",
                  relay2="on" if machine.Pin(control.relay_gpio[1]).value() else "off",
                  timer="on" if control.timer.is_active() else "off",
                  relay="on" if control.relay.is_on() else "off",
                  tasks=[task.__repr__() for task in control.timer.tasks],
                  samples=[sample.__repr__() for sample in control.stats.stats()],
                  threads=[thread.__repr__() for thread in control.threads]
                  )

    conn.send(ujson.dumps(status))
```

Si te fijas, hay cuatro casos en que es necesario consultar un valor lógico para determinar si poblar con "on" u "off" una llave del diccionario. Como es una operación común, definiré una función separada `bool2str` para determinar el valor:

```
def send_status(conn):
    """Envia el estado de la aplicacion en format JSON"""

    def bool2str(valor):
        return "on" if valor else "off"

    [conn.send(line) for line in headers]

    status = dict(temperature=control.temperature,
                  humidity=control.humidity,
                  uptime=util.uptime(),
                  memfree=str(gc.mem_free()),
                  date=util.time2str(),
                  relay1=bool2str(machine.Pin(control.relay_gpio[0]).value()),
                  relay2=bool2str(machine.Pin(control.relay_gpio[1]).value()),
                  timer=bool2str(control.timer.is_active()),
                  relay=bool2str(control.relay.is_on()),
                  tasks=[task.__repr__() for task in control.timer.tasks],
                  samples=[sample.__repr__() for sample in control.stats.stats()],
                  threads=[thread.__repr__() for thread in control.threads]
                  )

    conn.send(ujson.dumps(status))
```